# Lightning Components Redirection

Tags: lightning-aura-components, profile, dashboard, button

I have 3 components namely Employee Division which will show his division details like manufacturing,accounts etc and Employee Profile which will show his Profile details and an Dashboard Component where we will have 2 buttons say division and profile.I need to load division  component when Division button is pressed and similarly profile.
Is there any way to load this **without using  window.location.href**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create the lightning components on click of button and add it into the `v.body` of the current displayed component. Here is an example

Have the following code in your division button click:

```
goToDiv : function(component, event, helper){
    $A.createComponent(
                "c:EmployeeDivisionCmp",
                {
                    "aura:id": "empDivId"
                },
                function(newComp){
                    if (component.isValid()) {
                      var body = component.get("v.body");
                      body = [];
                      body.push(newComp);
                      component.set("v.body", body);
                   }
                }
            );
}
```

Now this should remove the current UI elements from the display and load the EmployeeDivisionCmp in the view.

Just being curious, how were you planning to redirect lightning components using `window.href.location`?

Comment: window.location.href ="/c/ComponentRedirectApp.app?componentName=EmployeeDivisionCmp"

Comment: Okay, componentName is standard variable or your custom attribute in ComponentRedirectApp?

Comment: probably it may change that's way looking for an alternate way to change it to make redirection in some other way.

Comment: You can try the one I mention, it works for me pretty well and its salesforce standard too.

Comment: It works fine but I cant able to hide existing component when new component is loaded.

Comment: `body = [];` should do the trick. It empties the list of components/elements in the current view.

Comment: Glad I could help. The question has been put on hold by Seniors. You might want to add your problem code for better understanding & keeping the best interest of the future community users.